# error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory using Selenium Gitlab pipeline with docker

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, selenium-grid

docker-compose yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.3-20220327
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.1.3-20220327
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.1.3-20220327
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.3-20220327
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

gitlab yml file

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository

.base:
  except:
    - tags

.base_test:
  extends: .base
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  image: docker/compose:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker-compose up

stages:
  - build
  - test
  
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target

build:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
    
test:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./TestReport/*
    expire_in: 7 days
```

Remote url in test script

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setCapability("se:recordVideo", true);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver((new URL("http://docker:4444/wd/hub")), options);
```

Pipeline error when executing the stage : test

```
/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
selectTemplateTest2 started!
selectTemplateTest2 skipped!
Extent Reports Version 3  Test Suite is ending!
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 1.7 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] init(templateTest.TemplateSelectorTest2)  Time elapsed: 1.473 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'runner-5ahk-ct-project-4846-concurrent-0', ip: '172.18.0.12', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-105-generic', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
[ERROR] tearDown(templateTest.TemplateSelectorTest2)  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.quit()" because "this.driver" is null
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   TemplateSelectorTest2>WorkspaceAppTestBase.init:43->TestBase.initialize:42 » SessionNotCreated
[ERROR]   TemplateSelectorTest2>WorkspaceAppTestBase.tearDown:57->TestBase.browserTearDown:57 » NullPointer
```

Can someone please help me fix this Gitlab pipeline issue?

I have set Gitlab pipeline to run selenium tests with grid setup  using docker-compose yml file but it seems remoteWebdriver url  connection is not working with  grid setup

Locally it works fine when i have docker running , docker compose up and then run the testng xml file

Solution:

Update
gitlab yml file

```
variables:
MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository

stages:
- build
- test

cache:
paths:
  - .m2/repository
  - target

build:
image: docker/compose:latest
stage: build
services:
  - name: docker:dind
script:
  - docker-compose up -d
tags:
  - docker-in-docker
  
test:
image: maven:latest
stage: test
script: 
  - mvn test
tags:
  - docker-in-docker
artifacts:
  paths:
    - ./TestReport/*
  expire_in: 7 days
```

Then to resolve the *cannot create new session error*, i had to provide reference to organization specific remote url in browser initialization file

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...implies that there was an error loading the shared library ***libnss3.so*** and possibly it is outdated or wasn't installed at all.

---

### Solution

Install *`libnss`* as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install
apt install libnss
apt install libnss3-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libxss-dev
```

As an alternative you can also:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnss3-dev libxss-dev
```

---

### Update

Search for the packages:

```
apt-cache search libnss
apt-file search  libnss3.so
```

Link to Packages: [Package Search Results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnss&searchon=names)

---

### tl; dr

[[BUG] Failed to launch the browser process: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/164)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/undetected-selenium  New to gitlab yml config.. Can you let me know how can i  instal libnss from my gitlab yml file

Comment: @Sal Did you issue got resolved? I have given you the specific commands you will require to execute.

Comment: Not yet.. I am unsure how to install it via yml file. as apt  / apk (also tried) not found whn i add it to yml file

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Using docker image for maven:latest 
$ apt-get install
/usr/bin/bash: line 123: apt-get: command not found

Similarly for sudo .. sudo not found

Comment: @Sal Did you check the github discussion?

Comment: Issue got fixed.  I moved running docker-compose  to build stage and then libnss no more showed up.   
Later error with  "Could not start a new session"  was due to incorrect remote url

Comment: @Sal Glad to be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

here was my error:

> /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.30' not found
> (required by/home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)

Even though I was working in a different system try. But for anyone having my error I fixed it with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t bullseye libnss3

apt show libnss3
```

run apt show before and after to see any changes in your version.
These commands updated and installed my missing libnss3.so package

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install libnss3` or something like that